# ASP.NET MVC view to controller dynamic javascript

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I can get static data in my controller but I don't know how to get data which I create dynamically by javascript.

When I fill the form and press "submit", my controller gets only static data "formHead" and dynamic data "fields" are null. Can anyone help me?

Here is my cshtml

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="formHead">
        <div id="fields" name="fields">
        // here I create fields by pressing a-link below and fill data
        </div>
        <a href="#" onclick="createField()">+ Add field</a>
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Here is my controller

```
public string FrontendForm(FormEditor formEditor)
{
    return "Success";
}
```

My model class:

```
public class FormEditor
{
    public string formHead { get; set; }
    public IList<Field> fields { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First please change your model to like this:

```
public class FormEditor
{
    public string formHead { get; set; }
    public IList<string> fields { get; set; }
}
```

Then add code for javascript to append fields in the div whose id is fields

```
<script>
var globalFieldCount=0;
function createField(){

$('#fields').append('<input type="text" id="fields' + globalFieldCount +'" name="fields[' + globalFieldCount + ']" >')
globalFieldCount++;

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by appending the dynamically created values to a form element before submitting the form using javascript.

```
- html -
<input type="hidden" id="fields" name="fields">

<input type="text" id="dynamic_field_1" name="dynamic_field_1">
<input type="text" id="dynamic_field_2" name="dynamic_field_2">

- javascript -

 $('form').submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var dynamicData;
  dynamicData.push($('#dynamic_field_1').val());
  dynamicData.push($('#dynamic_field_2').val());
  $('#fields').val(dynamicData);
  $('form').submit();
 });
```

or you can simply achieve this by submitting your form through an ajax request since you have the flexibility of creating the post data object with the dynamic data.

```
 $('form').submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({           
     type:"post",
     url: '@Url.Action("FrontendForm")',
     data: function(data){
      data. formHead = $('#formHead').val()
      var dynamicData;
      dynamicData.push($('#dynamic_field_1').val());
      dynamicData.push($('#dynamic_field_2').val());
      data.fields = dynamicData;
     },
     success: function(result) {
        // on success function
     }
    });
  });
```